# SQL query in JSP file pulling variable from VXML file

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

I'm trying to get an SQL query to work within a JSP file. The JSP file is pulled by a VXML file here is my JSP file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<% boolean success = true; // Always optimistic
 String info = "";
 String schoolname = request.getParameter("schoolname");
 String informationtype = request.getParameter("informationtype");

 try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        String connectString = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5435/N0176359";
        String user = "****";
        String password = "*****";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectString, user, password);
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
  ResultSet rsvp = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM lincolnshire_school_information_new WHERE school_name=\'"+schoolname+"\'");
        rsvp.next();
       info = rsvp.getString(2);
 }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
         success = false; // something went wrong
 }
%>
```

As you can see I'm trying to insert the value of the variable declared as "schooname" into the end of the SQL query. However when I come to run the jsp file it doesn't work and I get an error "ResultSet not positioned properly". When I put a standard query in (without trying to make it value of the variable it works fine)

Hope that makes sense, and thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks OK to me, I suspect it is something to do with the parameter you're passing - I suggest the following debugging steps:

1) Can you print the value of the schoolname parameter and verify it is what you think it is?

2) Can you form the SQL statement in a variable before you execute it, and print that too?

You might also want to check the boolean return value of your `rsvp.next()` call. If it is false, then there were no rows returned by your query. (javadoc for [ResultSet.next()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29))

Comment: Hi,

I've tried using the prepared statement and it doesn't work.

I appears to pass the variable successfully because I can get it to talk out the variable.

Comment: OK, how's about printing the SQL statement so we can see it and grabbing that return code?

Answer (score 0):

You're ignoring the outcome of [`ResultSet#next()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) before attempting to access the columns of the row. The `ResultSet#next()` returns `true` if there is a row, otherwise `false`. If you attempt to access a non-existing row, then you will get this kind of exception.

So, change the following two lines

```
    rsvp.next();
    info = rsvp.getString(2);
```

as follows:

```
    if (rsvp.next()) {
        info = rsvp.getString(2);
    }
```

This way the code won't anymore attempt to access a non-existing row. The next question would probably be: "why didn't it return a row"? The answer would be: "either the SQL query is wrong, or the row is actually not in the DB". This problem lies then outside the scope of Java/JSP/JDBC. Debug the SQL query (run a debugger, or just do a `System.out.println()` of it) and copypaste it unchanged into a DB admin tool and verify/execute it. My bet that those superflous backslashes are the root cause of the problem, or that the `schoolname` itself contains a character which needs to be escaped.

That said, this code doesn't belong in a JSP file. It belongs in a real Java class. Start [learning servlets](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html) before it's too late. Also I would learn the JDBC once again based on the [Sun tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/index.html), your JDBC code is namely leaking resources. You need to release (close) them after use in the `finally` block of the `try` block as you acquired them. Also I would use `PreparedStatement` instead of `Statement` to save your code from [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). The aforementioned Sun tutorial covers it as well.